# Variable on two onclick action with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, click

I try to create a variable on click, and to use it on another onclick action.
But it seems that the variable doesn't exist when the second onclick try to use it.

```js
$( "#search" ).click(function() {
    var myVariable = $(document).scrollTop();
});

$( "#gachette" ).click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:myVariable}, 10);
});
```

Do you have an idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

make your variable global.

```
$( "#search" ).click(function() {
   myVariable = $(document).scrollTop(); //global variable remove var from starting
});
```

`var` makes your variable local to the scope.

or declare you variable outside

```
var myVariable;
$( "#search" ).click(function() {
   myVariable = $(document).scrollTop();
});
```

Read [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) and [Variable Scope (JavaScript)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx)

Comment: ^^ Yeah, this will work :s  Have a +1 to balance the silliness.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i"m looking for. I can't declare the variable outside, because i need to have the scroll position when the user click on #search. THANKS !

Answer (score 1):

It's all about scope

```
var myVariable; // DEFINE OUTSIDE!

$( "#search" ).click(function() {
    myVariable = $(document).scrollTop(); // DON'T USE var HERE
});

$( "#gachette" ).click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:myVariable}, 10);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

And without globals :

```
$("#search").on('click', function() {
    $("#gachette").data('scrollTop', $(window).scrollTop());
});

$("#gachette").on('click', function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).data('scrollTop')}, 10);
});
```